# How to Switch Video Cameras Using WebRTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I am currently working on WebRTC multipeer connection. I want to be able to switch the camera that is being used in the middle of a call, without having to change the selected camera in Settings.
I followed along with the code from [this RTC example](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/), and it works, but only client side.

`devices.js`

```js
'use strict';

const videoElement = document.querySelector('#local');
const audioInputSelect = document.querySelector('select#audioSource');
const audioOutputSelect = document.querySelector('select#audioOutput');
const videoSelect = document.querySelector('select#videoSource');
const selectors = [audioInputSelect, audioOutputSelect, videoSelect];

audioOutputSelect.disabled = !('sinkId' in HTMLMediaElement.prototype);

function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
  // Handles being called several times to update labels. Preserve values.
  const values = selectors.map(select => select.value);
  selectors.forEach(select => {
    while (select.firstChild) {
      select.removeChild(select.firstChild);
    }
  });
  for (let i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
    const deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
    if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audioinput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || `microphone ${audioInputSelect.length + 1}`;
      audioInputSelect.appendChild(option);
    } else if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audiooutput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || `speaker ${audioOutputSelect.length + 1}`;
      audioOutputSelect.appendChild(option);
    } else if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || `camera ${videoSelect.length + 1}`;
      videoSelect.appendChild(option);
    } else {
      console.log('Some other kind of source/device: ', deviceInfo);
    }
  }
  selectors.forEach((select, selectorIndex) => {
    if (Array.prototype.slice.call(select.childNodes).some(n => n.value === values[selectorIndex])) {
      select.value = values[selectorIndex];
    }
  });
}

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(gotDevices).catch(handleError);

// Attach audio output device to video element using device/sink ID.
function attachSinkId(element, sinkId) {
  if (typeof element.sinkId !== 'undefined') {
    element.setSinkId(sinkId)
        .then(() => {
          console.log(`Success, audio output device attached: ${sinkId}`);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          let errorMessage = error;
          if (error.name === 'SecurityError') {
            errorMessage = `You need to use HTTPS for selecting audio output device: ${error}`;
          }
          console.error(errorMessage);
          // Jump back to first output device in the list as it's the default.
          audioOutputSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
        });
  } else {
    console.warn('Browser does not support output device selection.');
  }
}

function changeAudioDestination() {
  const audioDestination = audioOutputSelect.value;
  attachSinkId(videoElement, audioDestination);
}

function gotStream(stream) {
  window.stream = stream; // make stream available to console
  videoElement.srcObject = stream;
  // Refresh button list in case labels have become available
  return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.log('navigator.MediaDevices.getUserMedia error: ', error.message, error.name);
}

function start() {
  if (window.stream) {
    window.stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
      track.stop();
    });
  }
  const audioSource = audioInputSelect.value;
  const videoSource = videoSelect.value;
  const constraints = {
    audio: {deviceId: audioSource ? {exact: audioSource} : undefined},
    video: {deviceId: videoSource ? {exact: videoSource} : undefined}
  };
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(gotStream).then(gotDevices).catch(handleError);
}

audioInputSelect.onchange = start;
audioOutputSelect.onchange = changeAudioDestination;

videoSelect.onchange = start;

start();
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I think it would have something to do with tracks, not really sure as I just started working with WebRTC.

If you want to view the full code for the repository, click [here](https://github.com/divinelemon/VideoChatAppSwitchMics/blob/master/assets/js/devices.js)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To switch cameras, you must release the first camera's MediaStream by stopping all its tracks, then you must use getUserMedia() to get another MediaStream for the other camera. The browser won't prompt your user for permission again in this case; the camera will just switch. As you stop the tracks, call .removeTrack() on your rtcPeerConnection. Then, with the new stream's tracks, call .addTrack().

You may already know this, but enumerateDevices() returns much more useful information if you have an open MediaStream. That's because the user has granted permission.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the video sent to the remote end, you need to call RTCPeerConnection.replaceTrack. As usual, [mdn has a good example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack)

Comment: could you give me a code example? Thanks! Also, which file would i use RTCpeerConnection? The `rtc.js` file is diferent than the file which i try to switch videos, would this effect it? Thanks!